# How to generate dialogflow intent, training phrases and text response from the given document using LLM and chatgpt

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx, chatgpt-api, vector-database

I am working on a project in which, I can scrape user's website, and from that scraped content, I need to generate personalised dialogflow intent, training phrases and text response using LLM, pinecone and ChatGPT.

Right now I can generate intent, training phrases and text response, but the content of text response is generalised, not personalised that I need from the given source.

Is there any way that I can generate the personalised text response with the intent through chatGPT, pinecone and LLM ?